# I want to check if the user has required permission to do CRUD operations on the api URL

Tags: node.js

The task was to verify if the user has the permission to perform CRUD operations in the given api, I was given a mongoDB database that contains all the api url that a user can perform CRUD operations on and what CRUD operations are permissible.

In my database which  I use to check for permission the api is store like

```
/accounts/events/{deviceID}/
/accounts/events/tag/{userID}/billing
...
...
```

Here you can see that params of the url are in curly bracket, but if I try to get the url from req.originalUrl, what I will get is a value and not a variable in curly brackets, so an exact matching of URL to find out if the user has permission to access the incoming URL is a problem

```
/accounts/events/98jhjgjc888888888gbvnv // Since deviceid is param
```

How can I effectively match the pattern of the whole url to get a very accurate matching?

Comment: I don't understand your question properly. I think if you write more detail for your question, the question will be better than now. Or I don't know the answer of your question :)

Comment: I ll try to reframe the question

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem, I split the url using .split("/") and matched word by word with the api in my mongodb database which is also had identical split operation done on them, but ignoring the word which starts with "{". This gives me a fairly accurate match.
///This is the approach
["",api,events,tags,{userID}]
["",api,events,tags,9hsjiakhdsls]
So, I compare both the url but effectively ignore any element that starts with {